# Downside of adding partitions for the future?

Tags: partitioning, db2, db2-luw

I'm considering moving some of our large log-table to range partitioning for ease of archiving them. They are rarely used for queries, other than support and related stuff. Say my oldest data is from 2013 and I will be using 1 partition per year. What negative effects will it have if I add partitions for a couple of years ahead (say until 2025)? Also, will it be ok to use a timestamp column as a partitioning key, or is there any advantage in using a generated column for the year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What negative effects will it have if I add partitions for a couple of years ahead

None. A partition is basically an invisible table, so you'll have a handful of extra rows in various catalog tables and four preallocated extents per empty partition.

> will it be ok to use a timestamp column as a partitioning key, or is there any advantage in using a generated column for the year

I don't see any reason to use a generated column. I don't think the optimizer will be able to eliminate partitions defined on `year(timestamp_column)` given a search predicate on `timestamp_column` itself, so you'll likely need to modify existing queries to take advantage of partition elimination. Also, if you want partitioned indexes, you'd need to add the partitioning key column to them, and `year(timestamp_column)` as an index column is useless from pretty much any other aspect.

Comment: Thanks, that was my suspicion. The primary use will be to detach partitions as they grow old. The tables are really only used to investigate bugs.